# How to start CSS animation ONLY after page has fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I have a css preloader which runs until the page has fully loaded. Which is then removed with JS.
However, I also have a CSS animation for the home page which is beginning before the page has fully loaded which I want to change to run only once the page has fully loaded and the preloader has been removed of course.

For display purposes, I have added multiple youtube videos (to increase loading time) and I have made the `#preloader {opacity: .5}`. As you can see the Preloader and it's animation is removed once the page is fully loaded through the use of Javascript.

Unfortunately, however, the rest of the animations can be seen running in the background while the page is still loading and is finished by the time the page has fully loaded. Which defeats the purpose.

Ideally, I would prefer a solution using Javascript as I'm trying to learn the language. Nevertheless, Thanks in advance for your time any help.

```js
var preloader = document.getElementById("preloader");

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  preloader.style.display = 'none';
});

// var svgContainer = document.getElementById("svg-container");

// window.addEventListener('load', function(){
//  svgContainer.style.display = 'block';
// })

 // $(window).on("load", function() {
   
$(window).load(function(){
   $('.bullsHead').addClass('bullsHead');
   $('.logoGroup-bounceIn').addClass('logoGroup-bounceIn');
   $('.svg-container').addClass('svg-container');
});

 //  });
```

```css
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


#preloader {
font-family: 'Adam CG', sans-serif;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #333333;
z-index: 99;
opacity: .5;
}


.loading_r {
    color: #fbb03b;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-family: ;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-animation: loading_r 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    animation: loading_r 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s 0.5s ease
}

.loading_r .period {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: loading_r_period 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    animation: loading_r_period 3s ease-in-out infinite
}

@-webkit-keyframes loading_r {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0, 0);
        transform: scale(1) translate(0, 0)
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0, 0);
        transform: scale(1) translate(0, 0)
    }
    68% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(-0.5em, 0);
        transform: scale(1) translate(-0.5em, 0)
    }
    85% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0, 0);
        transform: scale(1) translate(0, 0)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0, 0);
        transform: scale(1) translate(0, 0)
    }
}
@keyframes loading_r {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0, 0);
        transform: scale(1) translate(0, 0)
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0, 0);
        transform: scale(1) translate(0, 0)
    }
    68% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(-0.5em, 0);
        transform: scale(1) translate(-0.5em, 0)
    }
    85% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0, 0);
        transform: scale(1) translate(0, 0)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0, 0);
        transform: scale(1) translate(0, 0)
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes loading_r_period {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg);
        transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg)
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0.5em, 0) rotate(-360deg);
        transform: translate(0.5em, 0) rotate(-360deg)
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(-360deg);
        transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(-360deg)
    }
    70% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(-360deg);
        transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(-360deg)
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0.2em, 0) rotate(-360deg);
        transform: translate(0.2em, 0) rotate(-360deg)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(-360deg);
        transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(-360deg)
    }
}
@keyframes loading_r_period {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg);
        transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg)
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0.5em, 0) rotate(-360deg);
        transform: translate(0.5em, 0) rotate(-360deg)
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(-360deg);
        transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(-360deg)
    }
    70% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(-360deg);
        transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(-360deg)
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0.2em, 0) rotate(-360deg);
        transform: translate(0.2em, 0) rotate(-360deg)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(-360deg);
        transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(-360deg)
    }
}



/*SVG's CSS Manipulation With External CSS; 
Link SVG to External CSS using the following:
animation: | name| duration| timing-function|delay| iteration-count| direction
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="../style.css"?>*/
/* -----------
LOGO
-------------- */

.svg-container {
    background-color: #333;
    animation: svg-container 3s linear 1s;
    transition: all .25s ease-in 2s;
}

.logoGroup-bounceIn {

    animation: logoGroup-bounceIn 3s ease-in 1s;
    transition: all .25s ease-in 2s;
}

.bullsHead {
    animation: bullsHead 3s ease-in 1s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transition: all .25s ease-in 2s;
}


@keyframes svg-container {
    0% {background: #4DAF7C}
    50% {background: #F2784B}
    100% {background:#34495E}
}

@keyframes logoGroup-bounceIn {
    0% {transform: translateY(-300px)}
    50% {transform: translateY(150px)}
    100% {transform: translateY(0px)}
}

@keyframes bullsHead {
 0% {transform: rotateY(0deg)}
 100% {transform: rotateY(180deg)}

}

.bullsShadow {
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.svg {
    width: 100%;
    /*height: auto;*/
}

/* -----------
HOVER BUTTON
-------------- */


.svg-wrapper {
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  width: 320px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.shape {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-dasharray: 170 540;
  stroke-dashoffset: -458;
  stroke-width: 8px;
  stroke: #ECA400;
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  line-height: 32px;
  position: relative;
  top: -48px;
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 140 540;
    stroke-dashoffset: -474;
    stroke-width: 8px;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 760;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }
}

.svg-wrapper:hover .shape {
  -webkit-animation: 0.5s draw linear forwards;
  animation: 0.5s draw linear forwards;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Loader Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  
</head>
<body>
<div id="preloader"><span class="loading_r">R<span class="period">.</span></span></div>


<div id="svg-container" class="svg-container">
<svg class="svg logo-components" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1000" height="600" viewBox="0 100 1000 800"><switch>

<g id="logoGroup-bounceIn" class="logoGroup-bounceIn">
<g id="bullsHead" class="bullsHead">
<path fill="#854B1F" d="M512.6 327.3l75.9-5-29-22.2-25 3.9z"/><path fill="#F2C397" d="M647.6 322.3L587.3 366l-8.7-25.7 9.9-18h59.1"/><path fill="#F3E9E0" d="M739.3 217l-34.8 4.5L716 228l23.3-11"/><path fill="#A17D63" d="M716 228l24-6.5 1.8-3.1-2.5-1.4z"/><path fill="#BE9C80" d="M716 228l-26.2 88.8-25.3-6.7 40-88.6z"/><path fill="none" stroke="#F2F2F2" stroke-width=".25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M587.3 366l102.5-49.2"/><path fill="#D49262" d="M597 415.3l47.5-16L656 377l-59 38.3"/><path fill="#140100" d="M525.5 497.8v13l-13.9 5z"/><path fill="#3E292B" d="M587.5 365.9l-49.7 48.2 29.8 2.1z"/><path fill="#723D17" d="M573.3 401.8l29.5-38.8-15.5 3z"/><path fill="#864E26" d="M656.1 377.1l-82.8 24.7 29.5-38.7z"/><path fill="#A96D33" d="M573.3 401.8l23.7 13.5 59-38.3z"/><path fill="none" stroke="#F2F2F2" stroke-width=".25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M588.5 322.3l-9.9 18 8.7 25.7"/><path fill="#E18D55" d="M588.5 322.2l-75.9 5 25.2 86.9 50.7-91.9"/><path fill="#D1916D" d="M528 483.3l11 10.5 21.9-50.2-32.9 39.7"/><path fill="#E2B03A" d="M520.7 504.1l29.5 19.7-31.7-13.4z"/><path fill="#F5C34D" d="M550.2 523.8l6.1-4.4M550.2 523.8v16.6-16.6l-29.5-19.7 35.6 15.3v25.3L500 570.2v-7.8l50.2-22"/><path fill="#755848" d="M533.5 509.2l5.5-15.4 6 20.1zM546.9 522.6l-1.9 16.5-20.1-5.6 6.1-17.2z"/><path fill="#B47030" d="M560.9 443.6l-1.4 47.2-10.4 24.8-4.1-1.7-6-20.1z"/><path fill="#603813" d="M534.5 304l-13-4.1-8.9 27.4z"/><path fill="#AB6726" d="M512.6 327.3l25.2 86.9-37.8-48.3z"/><path fill="#D0985E" d="M560.9 443.7l6.7-27.5-29.8-2.1 23.1 29.6"/><path fill="#BA7E50" d="M578.6 340.4l-40.8 73.7 49.5-48z"/><path fill="#B68857" d="M587.3 366l102.5-49.2-42.1 42.1-28.7-2.2z"/><path fill="#EEDCC5" d="M664.5 310.1l25.3 6.7L587.3 366z"/><path fill="#895136" d="M500 305.5l-21.5-5.6 21.5 66 21.5-66-21.5 5.6"/><path fill="#D88B49" d="M500 365.9l-60.9 77.7L500 412l60.9 31.6-60.9-77.7"/><path fill="#854B1F" d="M487.4 327.3l-75.9-5 29-22.2 25 3.9z"/><path fill="#F2C397" d="M352.4 322.3l60.3 43.7 8.7-25.7-9.9-18h-59.1"/><path fill="#F3E9E0" d="M260.7 217l34.8 4.5L284 228l-23.3-11"/><path fill="#A17D63" d="M284 228l-24-6.5-1.8-3.1 2.5-1.4z"/><path fill="#BE9C80" d="M284 228l26.2 88.8 25.3-6.7-40-88.6z"/><path fill="none" stroke="#F2F2F2" stroke-width=".25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M412.7 366l-102.5-49.2"/><path fill="#D49262" d="M403 415.3l-47.5-16L344 377l59 38.3"/><path fill="#5F462A" d="M500 530.6l-24.9 2.9-20.1 5.6 30 13.2 15-2.8 15 2.8 30-13.2-20.1-5.6-24.9-2.9"/><path fill="#140100" d="M474.5 497.8v13l13.9 5z"/><path fill="#3E292B" d="M412.5 365.9l49.7 48.2-29.8 2.1z"/><path fill="#723D17" d="M426.6 401.5L397.2 363l15.5 3z"/><path fill="#864E26" d="M344 377l82.6 24.5-29.4-38.5z"/><path fill="#A96D33" d="M426.6 401.5L403 415.3 344 377z"/><path fill="none" stroke="#F2F2F2" stroke-width=".25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M411.5 322.3l9.9 18-8.7 25.7"/><path fill="#E18D55" d="M411.5 322.2l75.9 5-25.2 86.9-50.7-91.9"/><path fill="#D1916D" d="M472 483.3l-11 10.5-21.9-50.2 32.9 39.7"/><path fill="#E2B03A" d="M479.3 504.1l-29.5 19.7 31.7-13.4z"/><path fill="#F5C34D" d="M449.8 523.8l-6.1-4.4M449.8 540.4v-16.6M443.7 519.4l35.6-15.3-29.5 19.7v16.6l50.2 22v7.8l-56.3-25.5v-25.3"/><path fill="#755848" d="M466.5 509.2l-5.5-15.4-6 20.1zM453.1 522.6l1.9 16.5 20.1-5.6-6.1-17.2z"/><path fill="#B47030" d="M439.1 443.6l1.4 47.2 10.4 24.8 4.1-1.7 6-20.1z"/><path fill="#603813" d="M465.5 304l13-4.1 8.9 27.4z"/><path fill="#AB6726" d="M487.4 327.3l-25.2 86.9 37.8-48.3z"/><path fill="#D0985E" d="M439.1 443.7l-6.7-27.5 29.8-2.1-23.1 29.6"/><path fill="#BA7E50" d="M421.4 340.4l40.8 73.7-49.5-48z"/><path fill="#B68857" d="M412.7 366l-102.5-49.2 42.1 42.1 28.7-2.2z"/><path fill="#EEDCC5" d="M335.5 310.1l-25.3 6.7L412.7 366z"/><path fill="#FFE0D1" d="M500 530.6l-24.9 2.9-6.1-17.2 9.5-3.8 9.9 3.3-13.9-18v8.2l-8 3.2-5.5-15.4 11-10.5h56l11 10.5-5.5 15.4-8-3.2v-8.2l-13.9 18 9.9-3.3 9.5 3.8-6.1 17.2-24.9-2.9"/><path fill="#F4C094" d="M472 483.3l-32.9-39.7L500 412l60.9 31.6-32.9 39.7z"/></g>

<g id="bullsShadow" class="bullsShadow" opacity="0.6">
<image overflow="visible" width="576" height="21" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAkEAAAAWCAYAAADHEEjLAAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAA GXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAEhxJREFUeNrsnY12m7oWhCUnadKV 9v2ftKdpG1s34mrIaNhbErbb45xKa7EAAQInID5m/yiEWWaZZZZZZplllr+wxFu6mJRSlOuKxnSg +egUjWWrTZ6884fB9dCo0799HJnz3+dtmdeX5VK3TMfjcVk/nU7V9Pr6Gt+2Lct5jvW8v7WOZePY SG1s6rw5prxerrNa57ZQX6Yo9ctvl/NWdXkZ7ePvxuu4dpS8zOvG8Zvy8+fPZdLy8vKyTNcq3759 W6ZZbr88Pz8v0zXK09PTMlnl06dPy2SVu7u7ZdJyf3+/TLyO/eiYxMcfDoe8nHQ5z/N6mXAM6pZ5 jHHZ/vDwsO6b90M9zqN11jy3oXV5evsNXJ8wR7vYjrq8zsfhWG4H14K28jqm/NvWDiXGZVv+m6Er Rj2tV9tkuTXv1emyta71J2Pbiea6PDolo329Tv673Ey5v0EACjsA6K4zHwGjUSi6FJA8KAo74Cm+ 30uxCUN5O+a0X7WOhlCn69acVtZz5Y4C7en/06hf6+SaVhDKx6LDkbYiOqd8CWX/9W+S6wF/pb1l /9zRA2bKNhP+0bkq/KDu169fJvDgpcIQleu+fPkyBEyzTABqgQ2DOUNMvv8VtPOxb7Cw3sMKQ+XZ 8frglNsEkOTlsn/Cc56XS30qz1Kiw/H8pvJcryCUjyFAqK6J+wE889x3ADRyG3j+6ZhE++I6AS0W kCxzAZcVbNAu2tDrwDquSdsu6+8XI3U7oKcHOy3g2QM9I8BzNOZR+lG0Ew3QiwKAE4LOUKcUUBh2 vOkgy6NAdA4UjUDSENx0tkVWhQAifIzULSDAIIJtDD5oywIfC7z0f0Vgo+cyO7oCK2sdlB500twe nytvy2oUgx8uStdxbOl8TfghoFoBLK/jGAWivC1/lVuK0SyzXFpayo6l4nj1Cj9Y548V3Pd4XKB6 MAzRegU2UEN4rjCQd6aPiMTPGx5ZBR6CjXWOj7mGipAMSGHY8WAtMUQB7KTvSnQtpopDfxM+jwc/ 11R2WvvsAZ8kgGOBD6YDARC2oV890rvypP8jfv/cmhp0ExA0qAKpCQyAcz+wPKoQxd8ERaPKkLss 0LNZBkQ0VKZqmdUVhSqtaylY1JFF/ZIzoKnq7LijA3zw74DyBPgpX4Kx7FvB2VtdLPCi2wE11XUA esh8ZgK5ZQ4r0rlpQkN9Vo3yZL3ouPz48WPIbJbP+fXr14uftaxE5XPOUpfHx8cmgOwp379/HzJz 5XNa/x8tWdmButNShRyVJ3X63uqZoDaSPIeeilLVs/oix1UwpRN9wIWiRiX9YOHLpr6GFZtU2kjE Qi6E5Gtj+GHIE8hxTVkMP7rMkHRF4BmdTheoPgxArzTn9+TRuc9YDUry7rlJNejWlKCWCnRoqD/3 BD33MnkqkQVFsQNEPRgagaNRk9lmXXyCKgCyVCGFFAYT7G8pPwo+OBcrMAKu0YNa6byCmN5MU5mY 95b18hUbyd/JVM1IcYoEEFHNcq17D4eyOYz9h+Cf1DKH5Tb0pdrzL/pTagPga5bbK54vD5tZWfXJ 9WymYh8fVoQUIpoPAkEAqyJyfKW6FLhJAjAVABEYmaDGfjd6nAFuSZUgAbEKVAjM1mVuW81qWCZ1 aKN4WcDD6zvMWHvh5zRQv8fPx1J9Xkn9eZX3WzDuBf4dkeZD99yEIP+l5JmWLDUI04MBQvcNc9k5 DtWeSnQIvh/THnOZ63ek6oyl4DhqzQZamIDk2Aq2HEAKwfBJQntGR+eCEXVibNKzzHrx3cwe1zo1 h4m5LOh6S5G0fJgAPG8vmNXEhjpPCeJ9GIL0Sz9fT/7Kt1SjWf67xboXAKkKQWyq8oCI9kkw3Xr+ NT34kZc/nqH0bnl+55+3ezxlh2IAAqkziUxZiZ7DjSmMfQL5vGry4t/AbcnvqsxRaqZiZcZRuNbf SqC0QmZx+N6AC7dbjk8CRGHQlLUHdFrgM+rcrAAE+LkT9SdPvwz4uZPr4fdV8vrZWzKJ3apPkOc0 HDvKkKcGWTA04kgdw1iE2bkO1nucrLsKEQAgGFFlCi+eSUzbV7ObqkzsSE0Ozy0/pMoxWuGHoYUd uaEEYU4mLjfqjq+Dr1EdsfEFXjr1VeWBie5tW2QYKpFyS3sKOrPM8icKoOjtPkwAIoAQm28QgckR W7iHJfigMn3Jx0AzGgomLgYkAIOqSqz4WjBkqE6b8/My4EOcpCuliutVybGunc+jkMTnGlB8rmHq GoGecyO81N/nYLx/LcXnVN6ZJzJ/RefdffMmsfsP8syP+Ai11KFrKkIjqtCoIrQbhEi12fgMKdBo SL0CkQU4BAvVdqgxLYhSkxt1rlE7WjWZSdTYGgWWYYPC/01zn/oHhXc/oTV8niELAAXw8Zy0yVcp EvhUPkb8lc7qT26zqDuRv/7Nh9BxeFVzyFSLPkbJyl7v/zmoECW0h3tMVaFSl3CPwBwmALKCiTgn B4YVdUTmyDCBI8/vJ4mfjvr1WOdJzgu3Ah3LZKUAJGBlghDDD+rw9xP/JTVvheD4+BB0JcMcdi1z 1wj87AltPxrvtBb84LhD5z3XA6FpDrtQFdoLRC1I2gNB1/QbisZNNwxHFgDx/oAkqDQEIZvoMQYi jTbjdrRtBg5HTbIUoMhfnZbTNP+PxYFaf8/qB0XAArWmiliDIzXnTBKz2VqPvxXtH9lpGs7X9CKK 3KYHSrPMckFJfF9B8SEgql4w2TyFZYUhgAJgiP2P8nEcpMCQwpCf/X0IItY25TqSZcYyzFocRm4q PcZyL9x94xBtKUYMTZbPE6tHovyEnsrD5rAdIHQK1zF9HTrgY6nnbNbam3/PgyeGH8tRekLQBVBk Lfcg6dCg1j3JF/eax/aayMzrZ0ARJahSawzH6Z7JyE3GSNTiOl0roIjqpABlmcU2IetyPeiUI0CE Q+mzysNwxGH6GhKvUWnW/QPTHpyvnbxCI/fg6PZZZulC0I7tFW1wiDpHU5k3KvnwIFUErSdar9oC AKmPjpiQVN3ZmMM495BlUlP1R1SiTX3PAVphipUfrBNAmpFe4l9kqUB7FKAQxh2oGXZ4HhzzFL97 AsFOCnVYe0/VafVxH7avu//AHULq7GNGM3T2t/ZTp68Qag94yxs+GfQ7QsOW530gAEqcCJFAYt0P eYHKvpEe1PiuDP9/vTcPdQ6OTeRGAZJE17CZoy0DQvw/wvv5uU8HQCVSf7DcTcrlRKW0rgFRYb3/ 7QSdWW6tP0zl/lVn5pZjdGo8J6aPjpWscAe89Z5/doDeRKIpwFgKlMJRMPx+Wn5AGinmAVAgM5j4 IHqwExr1obGv934b/Xv38hb9leX+gz3orX9sK0eC2jW9YS6sdg9OHc8VAHTZWh92mDYiwFxTGZSR AgdsMhr25xk1eWliwmBEkGlGZyQ7ZGhjtYaWK7MWlB86TrNSr2YsVo84Fwn7BLEqpVm1B9SvPYrQ hKRZfkfflzrLG+WDQUhMXpVqQ7l6qgSKnK05FDMZL3tO0Po7OOKKMzQ7rGOat/Q3strEuX6MZIna lqkKUe6gxOYzVnyM7NDJuL5LHaFbZrGWPxCvayLEc4bDaKlXHxqk7j9AJ9DKS3AyAEcdv1p2UAWa a/gB7fUJ6obNC2yow3JlGiPgaZrEFGCM/D1urqHQiCAjhSiETvSWRpVxoczRmjxxraMOeo3eIj+f TUQaR30h+SJFh63jj9G+y98+vwywf3j3A9pAECdRhMP1BKFZLgUgvq84mSH5o63jdakCBB8hzu4c 3sPbq7GxyrNbwQ/5wCXe7oW+K+yoz5KTgdl6mSbL7GWpPJ7qQ0MHeWNXbUxgnPZITGFmaLwCQSMk vgdFp7Afiqz337mh8a3Jg6PTgLqUOpaYCUE7OoQ0CDyew5Yez7bUY/jzuYIuziqtkV3iG7SBEyhJ Rt4cM6w82NFeZrg9/Ifk2qplOrYKgacv0qjjiiFMHdfMIel6nUZnG9npmb9yy8siYtBWqEwcgl/q UL/+7jLI6wp8EiYfC1RtzAo56seKEJuRX/+t4mUL5+JFkOX7RpNsOuDDIe/rgKAMOW/3WsKgoZoJ mczbm6gx9Qs6w4RWOTvz8wr/IlaJVEHS5IMeIHmZq522mzDkqEwaXZYUxBrKTwiXhcefBredmxm6 lSTxtbHeUolGrTcTgnZIwLFzI6jHuwc+nNfgd+QH6oHOJZmkQ9gmLQzBCI0n+NGQec7po47MVobn aCkvhipkXhPOYSUzdMYuCwbERDJdBcs3CQBiDb6oUGIlZ2PFCP4/pPJE1BVwiQQ8sbzAAEQViFmJ EmeZ5dp9JMAHdSV79KJaYNT0vCHDEKtEpOgka6ibVnZpDXFnFabh85cMGKqGq2gpQcYwGAA3TwXa DNcR6szSQRIhNcfyMiK9FMaqY1SROhOGTjv3GTWNnRwzmZUt+lWmowDRsXGdFgzN6LAzzF/qEa/g cDRUACsZFMLhf4XzR5gfAZ5zFZ/uIKuGj8pGATIUoWCY1ry8PqZpqjE8RuWnZJ0r2AOyWspNd1gL I6maOSYZj0Mm6945LLMWxgyLZCqLCItnJYiACNmjXdOX9ZWfh6+YKtDfV6x7AfVa2OwlOaVSCZ1H /TqoaSiZo6EEBT9gZKPWcKSYN7SNZd6yPjScZzRZA6NqWDrgh7NQ87m8iC8jm3SlBkmqjlbUWJUr SExtbhLGAbC69lhhIzDUU4c889irAUUtM9mpZ/6aA6g6fxRjENXgKDqtLw39RyP198ho8ueaui6B npER5gM5PJt5fLxMzxzizsNOELxYoGOCBsOMlznaMod5ztRGDqBqhHnrq5NNaTwitlxzcExm1e/Q TNK6rH9P9iPKkMRARMNmxN4Aqv92mQOo3naxxpfjAVQJfJBks1KCeF1fyBmIYIrCMn0oJGPMrs16 Y8ibCqosZUjD7lVx6g2DESTnjwBUJfB4yRidbNXV+GN8PvYDMvyEmuH4O4HoGlmnWzA0AkTH0B9L rOc31AK+aQ470yQWBHBCaPv6qAKkiRK9DNDXAp4Q9g+c2oxC0sFOeZuTxdkcBoOP55HWrZHfPROV 5uMJ2/HDomalpvw7mxw+Opo0Oyt7ipSCDtdZx7b8iKAaQcHhKLSsAJEitPyGPH4YgU/Ey0iByBpA NQOINXbY58+fuw/Et2/flmmW31MyGF4DDp+fn5dpFEi55PvFG8ke2aDLvZaoPikQsS8QK0Jw1s/7 SdbpZIGPpcR6ZmfJ+N40o8lQHYkVIk8ZEtPYJq8PQdIG4lQVsuotEGuBD8x5hpLkwU8IYw7Te9f3 QtGl6pA10rzlIzTyTp8QNGAS826sY9gO4KZO0qP+PtcGnhD2jRDvqUCbZVVxJIli0FB6T9nQbMyt Dg9Q4B1jhZETSFTXD/CyBldtdayUJdo0jbGKBCdP/QK1AMgzi+XfBD8ghiEydUUySUSBrRkJNsvZ Kh1gyAGhBV5oe9U/Qgli+GFlhR2svZcUniMLYPSZ1IgyVmx1TDL+EIHyBNNfL3OzlxFa1R6GKf4N 3J9xYIQVoabDgKhpjAFIh+kQNan1/hpViPbsc+kYZC0wOobxcPtWbqSbM4XdFASJSSw5ik8I775B XA+o4bFNjjtNXZeqOWEQgnbDDz/IMihopcJo5FfHKblSYzwQYtVGzFNufiEeygLrPIyF0g86Jwti PMjBssKOmLnWDh05g3gfXBf5XESS7SOrPQw+by+rWF5YG+DBSPMvLy/LNMvfVaDWjapBFgipQvT0 9LRMoTgEy32VCjglwFFWgrAt37MPDw+JQCRhKBg2g/GHQp4AKFboPI9fpmORsfka++szzEoOR6Cx qUwVGc4o3VCCvAFgKyDzlCCcG07j8tKuAIkVImt0e0cZGoGhvdsuVYvOjTBLYX8uoakEnakKeeUU tgkLT1eCnr2qzZ65BTuuw7CahCSsfHXk1cFHrcFTacT3TXsagSVfVptQelV1dBBTGQk+0ldYVLs9 m8JwXRwVZmwPGvoOkwG2s1+F+lno9hJJE8mPJ9IXdyzmkkjmElMJUpOK90V/TplA9XGK5/R8bsn3 +T///LMsPz4+LpP2jzkfUL5Hyvbq5cOKUPYtwgueR5jnQsNtrLCE3EAwyzEcqdpCQ89UjtCessQk oaCBfeCbg7QABjitx/GHlKcw67l4XX2FjAFUNwkaGxm5R8xkIYyZ0Hrz36EanTpzL5Ltw5T/CTAA s9RR2YLlBdsAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" transform="translate(212.447 580.952)" opacity=".6"/>
</g>


<g id="logoText" stroke-miterlimit="10"><path fill="#FBB03B" stroke="#ECA400" d="M283.1 693.2h-8.5l-12.2-16.3h-5.5v16.3h-7.5V645h14.3c6.4 0 10.1 2.6 12 4.8 2.5 2.8 3.9 6.7 3.9 11.2 0 4.4-1.4 8.3-3.9 11.1-1.2 1.3-3 2.8-5.6 3.7l13 17.4zm-19.4-23c3.1 0 5.5-.9 7-2.6 1.8-2 2.1-4.7 2.1-6.6 0-2-.3-4.7-2.1-6.6-1.5-1.7-3.8-2.5-7-2.5h-6.8v18.3h6.8zM320.8 682.9h-17.2l-4.1 10.3h-8.3l21-50.4 20.9 50.4h-8.3l-4-10.3zm-2.8-6.7l-5.9-14.7-5.9 14.7H318zM346.8 689.4c-1.9-1.4-3.3-3.2-4.3-5.2-1.1-2.2-1.6-4.7-1.6-7.3V645h7.5v31.9c0 2.9 1 5.1 3 6.6 1.8 1.4 4.5 2.3 7.3 2.3s5.5-.8 7.3-2.3c2-1.5 2.9-3.7 2.9-6.6V645h7.6v31.9c0 2.7-.6 5.1-1.6 7.3-1 2-2.5 3.8-4.3 5.2-3.2 2.5-7.4 3.8-12 3.8s-8.7-1.3-11.8-3.8zm10.8-57.2h6.8l-6.8 7.6h-4.5l4.5-7.6zM418.5 693.2h-27.7V645h7.5v41.4h20.2v6.8zM460.1 664.6h17.6v6.8h-17.6v15h21.4v6.8h-29V645h29v6.8h-21.4v12.8zM502.5 662.2v31H495v-50.5l30.3 33.2V645h7.6v50.4l-30.4-33.2zM581.2 693.2h-8.5l-12.2-16.3H555v16.3h-7.5V645h14.3c6.4 0 10.1 2.6 12 4.8 2.5 2.8 3.9 6.7 3.9 11.2 0 4.4-1.4 8.3-3.9 11.1-1.2 1.3-3 2.8-5.6 3.7l13 17.4zm-19.4-23c3.1 0 5.5-.9 7-2.6 1.8-2 2.1-4.7 2.1-6.6 0-2-.3-4.7-2.1-6.6-1.5-1.7-3.8-2.5-7-2.5H555v18.3h6.8zM591.7 693.2V645h7.5v48.2h-7.5zM653 686.2l-.5.5 4.4 5.7-5.5 4.1-4.4-5.9c-.5.3-1.1.5-1.6.8-3 1.2-6.2 1.9-9.4 1.9-3.3 0-6.4-.7-9.4-1.9-2.9-1.2-5.5-3-7.7-5.2s-4-4.7-5.2-7.7c-1.2-2.9-1.9-6.1-1.9-9.4s.6-6.4 1.9-9.4c1.2-2.9 3-5.5 5.2-7.7s4.7-3.9 7.7-5.1c2.9-1.3 6.1-1.9 9.4-1.9 3.3 0 6.4.6 9.4 1.9 2.9 1.2 5.5 2.9 7.7 5.1 2.2 2.2 3.9 4.8 5.1 7.7 1.3 3 1.9 6.2 1.9 9.4s-.6 6.4-1.9 9.4c-1.3 2.9-3 5.5-5.2 7.7zm-10.7-1.8l-3.4-4.5 5.5-4.1 3.5 4.7c2.9-3.1 4.6-7.2 4.6-11.4 0-4.4-1.8-8.6-4.9-11.7s-7.3-4.9-11.7-4.9c-4.4 0-8.6 1.8-11.7 4.9s-4.9 7.3-4.9 11.7c0 4.4 1.8 8.6 4.9 11.7s7.3 4.9 11.7 4.9c2.3 0 4.4-.4 6.4-1.3zM677.9 689.4c-1.9-1.4-3.3-3.2-4.3-5.2-1.1-2.2-1.6-4.7-1.6-7.3V645h7.5v31.9c0 2.9 1 5.1 3 6.6 1.8 1.4 4.5 2.3 7.3 2.3s5.5-.8 7.3-2.3c2-1.5 2.9-3.7 2.9-6.6V645h7.6v31.9c0 2.7-.6 5.1-1.6 7.3-1 2-2.5 3.8-4.3 5.2-3.2 2.5-7.4 3.8-12 3.8-4.4 0-8.6-1.3-11.8-3.8zM729.4 664.6H747v6.8h-17.6v15h21.4v6.8h-29V645h29v6.8h-21.4v12.8z"/><path fill="#FFF" stroke="#FFF" d="M152.2 730.2l-5.9-13.4-5.5 13.4-10.2-23.2h3.8l6.3 14.7 3.7-9.2 1.8-4.6 2 4.5 4 9.3L158 707h3.8l-9.6 23.2zM169.8 716h8.1v3.1h-8.1v6.9h9.9v3.1h-13.4V707h13.4v3.1h-9.9v5.9zM198.7 722.6c0 1.1-.2 2.1-.7 3-.5.8-1.2 1.6-2 2.1-1.5 1-3.6 1.5-6.1 1.5H185V707h4.9c2.5 0 4.3.4 5.5 1.4.7.5 1.2 1.2 1.5 1.9.3.7.4 1.5.4 2.3 0 1.2-.4 2.7-1.7 4.1.4.2.7.5 1 .8.7.7 1.2 1.4 1.5 2.2.4.9.6 1.9.6 2.9zm-10.4-12.5v6.8c.7-.1 1.5-.4 2.3-.7 1.1-.5 2-1 2.6-1.6.6-.6.9-1.2.9-2 0-1.1-.4-1.5-.7-1.7-.8-.6-2.5-.8-3.6-.8h-1.5zm7.2 12.5c0-1.2-.4-2.1-1.2-2.8-.5-.5-1-.8-1.7-1.1-.3.1-.6.3-.9.4-1.2.5-2.5.8-3.4 1v6h1.4c1.9 0 3.4-.3 4.4-1 1-.6 1.4-1.3 1.4-2.5zM230 718.1c0 3.2-.9 5.8-2.7 7.8-1 1.1-2.2 1.9-3.6 2.5-1.4.6-3.1.9-4.9.9h-5.3V707h5.3c1.8 0 3.4.3 4.9.9 1.4.5 2.6 1.4 3.6 2.5 1.8 1.9 2.7 4.6 2.7 7.7zm-3.5 0c0-2.3-.6-4.2-1.8-5.5-1.3-1.5-3.3-2.2-5.8-2.2h-1.8v15.3h1.8c2.6 0 4.5-.8 5.8-2.2 1.2-1.2 1.8-3.1 1.8-5.4zM238.4 716h8.1v3.1h-8.1v6.9h9.9v3.1h-13.4V707h13.4v3.1h-9.9v5.9zM265.2 724.8c-.6 2.2-2.6 3.9-5 4.3-.5.1-.9.1-1.3.1-.9 0-1.8-.2-2.6-.5-1.4-.6-2.6-1.5-3.7-2.9l2.8-2.2c.6.8 1.4 1.4 2.2 1.7.7.3 1.4.3 2 .2 1.1-.2 2.1-1 2.3-1.9.3-1-.4-1.9-1-2.5-1-.9-2.6-2.5-2.7-2.6l-2.7-2.6c-.8-.8-1.4-1.7-1.7-2.7-.3-.9-.3-1.9-.1-2.8.3-1 .8-1.8 1.7-2.5.8-.6 1.7-1.1 2.7-1.3 1.1-.2 2.2-.2 3.3.2 1.1.5 2.2 1.2 3 2.3l-2.7 2.2c-1.1-1.4-2.3-1.4-2.9-1.3-.8.2-1.4.7-1.6 1.3-.1.4-.1 1.1.8 2l3.7 3.6c.5.5 1.2 1.2 1.7 1.6 1 .9 1.6 1.9 2 2.9.1 1.3.1 2.4-.2 3.4zM269.8 729.2V707h3.5v22.3h-3.5zM296.2 720.8v6l-.8.5h-.1l-.1.1-.1.1-.1.1-.1.1s-.1 0-.1.1c0 0-.1 0-.1.1-.1 0-.1 0-.1.1 0 0-.1 0-.1.1 0 0-.1.1-.2.1l-.1.1h-.1l-.1.1c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1-1.3.6-2.6.9-4 1h-.5c-1.2 0-2.4-.2-3.5-.6-.1 0-.2-.1-.3-.1-.2-.1-.3-.1-.5-.2-.4-.1-.8-.3-1.1-.5-.9-.5-1.7-1.1-2.5-1.9-1-1-1.8-2.2-2.4-3.5-.4-1-.7-2.1-.8-3.2 0-.4-.1-.8-.1-1.1v-.6c.1-1.3.4-2.6.9-3.8.6-1.3 1.4-2.5 2.4-3.5s2.2-1.8 3.5-2.4c1.3-.6 2.8-.9 4.3-.9h.8c1.3.1 2.5.4 3.8.9.1 0 .1.1.2.1v4.1c-.4-.4-1-.7-1.5-1-.4-.2-.9-.4-1.4-.5h-.1-.1-.1-.1c-.1 0-.3 0-.4-.1h-.2-.1-.1H289.6h-.1-.1-.1H289c-1.4 0-2.8.4-3.9 1.1l-.1.1c-.5.3-.9.7-1.3 1.1-.1.1-.3.2-.4.4-.1.2-.3.4-.4.5l-.1.1c-.1.1-.1.2-.2.3l-.1.1c-.5.7-.8 1.5-.9 2.3v.1c-.1.3-.1.6-.2.9v1.1c0 .6.1 1.1.3 1.7.4 1.3 1 2.4 1.9 3.3 1.4 1.4 3.4 2.3 5.4 2.3h1.1c.2 0 .5-.1.7-.1h.6c.4-.1.8-.3 1.2-.5v-4.1h-4.2v-3.2h7.7v2.6zM304.4 714.9v14.3h-3.5v-23.3l14 15.3V707h3.5v23.3l-14-15.4z"/><path fill="#FBB03B" stroke="#ECA400" d="M337 734.3h-2.9v-29h2.9v29z"/><path fill="#FFF" stroke="#FFF" d="M374.2 730.2l-5.9-13.4-5.5 13.4-10.2-23.2h3.8l6.3 14.7 3.7-9.2 1.8-4.6 2 4.5 4 9.3L380 707h3.8l-9.6 23.2zM391.9 716h8.1v3.1h-8.1v6.9h9.9v3.1h-13.4V707h13.4v3.1h-9.9v5.9zM420.7 722.6c0 1.1-.2 2.1-.7 3-.5.8-1.2 1.6-2 2.1-1.5 1-3.6 1.5-6.1 1.5H407V707h4.9c2.5 0 4.3.4 5.5 1.4.7.5 1.2 1.2 1.5 1.9.3.7.5 1.5.5 2.3 0 1.2-.4 2.7-1.7 4.1.4.2.7.5 1 .8.7.7 1.2 1.4 1.5 2.2.4.9.5 1.9.5 2.9zm-10.3-12.5v6.8c.7-.1 1.5-.4 2.3-.7 1.1-.5 2-1 2.6-1.6.6-.6.9-1.2.9-2 0-1.1-.4-1.5-.7-1.7-.8-.6-2.5-.8-3.6-.8h-1.5zm7.2 12.5c0-1.2-.4-2.1-1.2-2.8-.5-.5-1-.8-1.7-1.1-.3.1-.6.3-.9.4-1.2.5-2.5.8-3.4 1v6h1.4c1.9 0 3.4-.3 4.4-1 1-.6 1.4-1.3 1.4-2.5zM452.1 718.1c0 3.2-.9 5.8-2.7 7.8-1 1.1-2.2 1.9-3.6 2.5-1.4.6-3.1.9-4.9.9h-5.3V707h5.3c1.8 0 3.4.3 4.9.9 1.4.5 2.6 1.4 3.6 2.5 1.8 1.9 2.7 4.6 2.7 7.7zm-3.5 0c0-2.3-.6-4.2-1.8-5.5-1.3-1.5-3.3-2.2-5.8-2.2h-1.8v15.3h1.8c2.6 0 4.5-.8 5.8-2.2 1.2-1.2 1.8-3.1 1.8-5.4zM460.5 716h8.1v3.1h-8.1v6.9h9.9v3.1H457V707h13.4v3.1h-9.9v5.9zM484 721.7l5.9-14.7h3.8l-9.5 23.2-10.3-23.2h3.8l6.3 14.7zM501.3 716h8.1v3.1h-8.1v6.9h9.9v3.1h-13.3V707h13.3v3.1h-9.9v5.9zM529.1 729.2H516.4V707h3.5v19.1h9.3v3.1zM537.3 728.4c-1.4-.6-2.5-1.4-3.5-2.4s-1.8-2.2-2.4-3.5c-.6-1.3-.9-2.8-.9-4.3s.3-3 .9-4.3c.6-1.3 1.4-2.5 2.4-3.5s2.2-1.8 3.5-2.4c1.3-.6 2.8-.9 4.3-.9s3 .3 4.3.9c1.3.6 2.5 1.3 3.5 2.4 1 1 1.8 2.2 2.4 3.5.6 1.4.9 2.8.9 4.3s-.3 3-.9 4.3-1.3 2.5-2.4 3.5c-1 1-2.2 1.8-3.5 2.4-1.4.6-2.8.9-4.3.9s-2.9-.4-4.3-.9zm-1-15.7c-1.4 1.4-2.3 3.4-2.3 5.4s.8 4 2.3 5.4c1.4 1.4 3.4 2.3 5.4 2.3s4-.8 5.4-2.3c1.4-1.4 2.3-3.4 2.3-5.4s-.8-4-2.3-5.4c-1.4-1.4-3.4-2.3-5.4-2.3s-4 .9-5.4 2.3zM560.7 707h3.7c2.9 0 4.7 1.2 5.5 2.2 1.2 1.3 1.8 3.1 1.8 5.2s-.6 3.9-1.8 5.2c-.9 1-2.6 2.2-5.5 2.2h-3.1v7.5h-3.5V707h2.9zm7.9 7.3c0-.9-.2-2.1-1-3-.7-.8-1.8-1.2-3.2-1.2h-3.1v8.5h3.1c1.4 0 2.5-.4 3.2-1.2.8-.9 1-2.2 1-3.1zM593.1 729.2v-11.8l-7 10.4-7-10.4v11.8h-3.5V706l10.5 15.6 10.5-15.6v23.3h-3.5zM605.8 716h8.1v3.1h-8.1v6.9h9.9v3.1h-13.4V707h13.4v3.1h-9.9v5.9zM624.3 714.9v14.3h-3.5v-23.3l14 15.3V707h3.5v23.3l-14-15.4zM658.3 710.1h-6.1v19.1h-3.5v-19.1h-6.1V707h15.7v3.1z"/><path fill="#FBB03B" stroke="#ECA400" d="M675.5 734.3h-2.9v-29h2.9v29z"/><path fill="#FFF" stroke="#FFF" d="M709.7 729.2v-11.8l-7 10.4-7-10.4v11.8h-3.5V706l10.5 15.6 10.5-15.6v23.3h-3.5zM730.9 724.5H723l-1.9 4.8h-3.8L727 706l9.7 23.3h-3.8l-2-4.8zm-1.2-3.1l-2.7-6.8-2.7 6.8h5.4zM756 729.2h-3.9l-5.6-7.5H744v7.5h-3.5V707h6.6c2.9 0 4.7 1.2 5.5 2.2 1.2 1.3 1.8 3.1 1.8 5.2 0 2-.6 3.8-1.8 5.1-.5.6-1.4 1.3-2.6 1.7l6 8zm-8.9-10.6c1.4 0 2.5-.4 3.2-1.2.8-.9 1-2.2 1-3 0-.9-.2-2.2-1-3.1-.7-.8-1.8-1.2-3.2-1.2H744v8.5h3.1zM772.1 729.2l-8.8-10.1v10.1h-3.5V707h3.5v9.2l7.1-9.2h4.4l-8.2 10.7 9.8 11.5h-4.3zM784.7 716h8.1v3.1h-8.1v6.9h9.9v3.1h-13.4V707h13.4v3.1h-9.9v5.9zM814.1 710.1H808v19.1h-3.5v-19.1h-6.1V707h15.7v3.1zM818.3 729.2V707h3.5v22.3h-3.5zM831 714.9v14.3h-3.5v-23.3l14 15.3V707h3.5v23.3l-14-15.4zM867.9 720.8v6l-.8.5h-.1c-.1 0-.1.1-.1.1l-.1.1-.1.1-.1.1s-.1 0-.1.1c0 0-.1 0-.1.1-.1 0-.1 0-.2.1 0 0-.1 0-.1.1s-.1.1-.2.1l-.1.1h-.1l-.1.1c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1-1.3.6-2.6.9-4 1h-.5c-1.2 0-2.4-.2-3.5-.6-.1 0-.2-.1-.3-.1-.1-.1-.3-.1-.5-.2-.4-.1-.8-.3-1.1-.5-.9-.5-1.7-1.1-2.5-1.9-1-1-1.8-2.2-2.4-3.5-.4-1-.7-2.1-.8-3.2 0-.4-.1-.8-.1-1.1v-.6c.1-1.3.4-2.6.9-3.8.6-1.3 1.4-2.5 2.4-3.5s2.2-1.8 3.5-2.4c1.4-.6 2.8-.9 4.3-.9h.8c1.3.1 2.5.4 3.8.9.1 0 .1.1.2.1v4.1c-.5-.4-1-.7-1.5-1-.5-.2-.9-.4-1.4-.5h-.1-.1-.1-.1c-.1 0-.3 0-.4-.1h-.2-.2H861.2h-.1-.1-.1H860.6c-1.4 0-2.8.4-3.9 1.1 0 0-.1.1-.2.1-.5.3-.9.7-1.3 1.1-.1.1-.3.2-.4.4-.1.2-.3.4-.4.5l-.1.1c-.1.1-.1.2-.2.3l-.1.1c-.5.7-.8 1.5-.9 2.3v.1c-.1.3-.1.6-.2.9v1.1c0 .6.1 1.1.3 1.7.4 1.3 1 2.4 2 3.3 1.4 1.4 3.4 2.3 5.4 2.3h1.1c.2 0 .4-.1.7-.1h.6c.4-.1.8-.3 1.2-.5v-4.1H860v-3.2h7.7v2.6z"/></g></g></switch></svg>

 <div class="svg-wrapper">
   <svg height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <rect class="shape" height="60" width="320" />
   </svg>
    <div class="text">VIEW WORK</div>
 </div>
</div>

<!--  <div class="home"><object class="logoContainer" type="image/svg+xml" data="Logos/BullLogo.svg"></object></div> -->


 <div>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8DIkeyswMyY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>
<div>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8DIkeyswMyY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>
<div>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8DIkeyswMyY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>
<div>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8DIkeyswMyY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>
<div>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8DIkeyswMyY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>
<div>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8DIkeyswMyY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>
<div>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8DIkeyswMyY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about just moving your code in `$(window).load(function(){}` to `window.addEventListener('load', function(){}`?

Then it'll add the animation class after the preloader is removed. So then you'll see the animation. Now you're adding the animation before the preloader is removed, and that makes you won't see any animation,